# How to `sudo` when using fish protocol in Dolphin?

Tags: linux, ssh, arch-linux, kde, manjaro

I can connect to a remote server and browser the file system using Dolphin and the location `fish://me@my-server`. However, if I need to access the file system as a different user, or as root, how would I go about doing that.

1. open Dolphin
2. enter `fish://me@my-server` as the location and authenticate
3. browse to a protected directory
4. get message "could not enter folder"

How can I "enter the folder as root on the server"?

Answer (score -1):

4 years ago ... anyway, I'll reply. You must log as ROOT (root@your-server) if you want access to root folders.